# .aspx & c# how to change URL value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

I am having some trouble with a `URL` value that's set, I have below URL:

> http://localhost/myapp/Admin/ScheduleTaskDetail.aspx?id=1&mode=v

The modes are:

- v - View
- e - Edit
- a - New

I want to allow changes to the view page so when I click a button they can edit. I have managed to get this working by using the function that reads from the URL and changing its behavior there. However I don't know how to update the URL without a `response.redirect()`.

Is there a way to add code to a `onclick` event that will change the `&mode=??`

Unfortunately, I can't share code as its not my code to share.

This is part of a MVC c# / aspx project.

If there is a question answering this please let me know I couldn't find a match that was applicable.

Comment: You can execute JavaScript and that has the ability to rewrite the URL. I'm sure some quick Googling would tell you how to do it. Then it's just a matter of wiring up that JavaScript to your button.

Comment: i cant use javascript in this case. its all done via c# in a mvc application (i will add that detail to the question)

Comment: Why can't you use JavaScript? What is preventing you from doing so? What is preventing you from doing a Response.Redirect in C#?

Comment: because im not implementing javascript for one change in a .net project. Also i rather not use response.redirect as i dont want the page to reload, if i have to i will but hoping to see if its possible to make this single change without too much hassle. Sadly i am struggling.

Comment: Guess what? Client side code (JavaScript) is the only way to update a URL without actually navigating to a different page. Having a policy of not adding JavaScript to a web application is silly - learn to use the right tool for the job. Otherwise you can do a Response.Redirect  from the server to actually have the browser navigate to a different URL (changing the query string is considered a different URL by the browser, even if you end up hitting the same action methods in ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: i found a work around which solved another issue, but could not solve the url one. I asked the question as i was hoping there might be a way but as i don't want to implement javascript for one change i will close this question. Thank you for getting back to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change Browser URL without reloading using JavaScript**

The HTML Markup consists of 3 buttons which make a call to a function ChangeUrl. This function accepts the page Title and URL as parameters.

It first checks whether browser supports HTML5 and if yes then a State object containing the page Title and URL is created and is passed to the HTML5 History pushState method along with the page Title and URL as the other two parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Page1" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page1', 'Page1.htm');" />
<input type="button" value="Page2" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page2', 'Page2.htm');" />
<input type="button" value="Page3" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page3', 'Page3.htm');" />
```

**Change Browser URL without reloading using jQuery**

The HTML Markup consists of 3 buttons to which the jQuery click event handler has been assigned. Inside the jQuery click event handler, a function ChangeUrl is being called which accepts the page Title and URL as parameters.

This function first checks whether browser supports HTML5 and if yes then a State object containing the page Title and URL is created and is passed to the HTML5 History pushState method along with the page Title and URL as the other two parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
        if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
            var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
            history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
        } else {
            alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    }
    $(function () {
        $("#button1").click(function () {
            ChangeUrl('Page1', 'Page1.htm');
        });
        $("#button2").click(function () {
            ChangeUrl('Page2', 'Page2.htm');
        });
        $("#button3").click(function () {
            ChangeUrl('Page3', 'Page3.htm');
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Page1" id="button1" />
<input type="button" value="Page2" id="button2" />
<input type="button" value="Page3" id="button3" />
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have done a work around in the end which ignored the url but just updated all the contents of the page based off a setting ive created to know the what state the page should be. However if i come back the code i will implement this as its exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better approach instead of trying to shoe horn in the use of URL query strings is to just use a control on the page which triggers the V, E, A values and fires the appropriate event depending on what the user clicks/selects. So for example a dropdownlist with V, E, and A. User selects the value they want then the binding is done at the selectedindexchange event. You can use updatePanels if you only want to refresh a applicable section of the page.